# Code works on Eclipse IDE but not on Command Prompt (error:package net.proteanit.sql does not exist)

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, command-prompt

There are no errors when I run my code in Eclipse. However, when I try to run it on the command prompt, I get 2 errors that are related to each other. [image: Error on command prompt]

I reimported the rs2xml jar file, yet it still gave me the same error.

Comment: You have to provide the [_classpath_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#standard-options).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose how? like in the environment variable?

Comment: Read the link. You have to specify the `--class-path` command option or set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable

Comment: `javac` means compile your code, not run your code. In the run/launch configuration there the button _Show Command Line_ to get the command line to run your already compiled code.

Comment: @pingutong You really should read the very good documentation for which I provided you the link. It explains how to use the `javac` CLI tool.